# How to delete a direction markers in google map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to delete a google map direction markers after a search without reloading the page. I've made an example but its not working :

```
//First of all testing if there is already a direction on the map

if(directionsService != null) 
{
  directionsService.setMap(null);
  directionsService = null;
}

  //Then display the new one

  var origin = $('#de').val();
  var destination = $('#en').val();
  var request = {
        origin      : origin,
        destination : destination,
        travelMode  : google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING 
    }

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(); 
            directionsService.route(request, function(response, status){ 
                if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
                    direction.setDirections(response); 
                    showSteps(response);
                }
    });
```

all this code is on a function called by a click event

```
<button id="envoyer" id=="env" onclick="javascript:c()">Send</button>
```

so any one have an idea thanks  !

**Update**

```
function showSteps(directionResult) {
  var markerArray = [];
  var myRoute = directionResult.routes[0].legs[0];

  for (var i = 0; i < myRoute.steps.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myRoute.steps[i].start_location,
      map: map
    });
    attachInstructionText(marker, myRoute.steps[i].instructions);
    markerArray[i] = marker;
  }
}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, `directionsService.setMap(null);` should make the direction at least invisible, `directionService = null` would delete it alltogether then. What do you mean by "it's not working"?

Comment: It deletes the itinerary but not the markers

Comment: well, show your `showSteps` - function then, we can't guess what you do in there

Comment: i've added it in the text !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When clearing the itinerary, using `directionsService.setMap(null);` you will have to remove the MapMarkers, which aren't directly connected to the Direction - Service, seperately too.

You have already stored them in `markerArray` inside of your `showSteps` - function, so you would need to move this variable out of the function into an outer scope or let the function return it to be able to access it.

By doing this, you can simply loop over the markerArray and call `.setMap(null)` on each stored Marker, thus removing them from the map.

```
var markerArray = [];

function showSteps(directionResult){

// your code

}

//function to remove MapMarkers
function removeMapMarkers(){

    for(var i=0; i<markerArray.length; i+=1){
        markerArray[i].setMap(null)
    }

    markerArray = [];

}
```

Comment: Thanks it's working, my fault that i declare the markerArray inside the function and not outside